# Cordova file transfer plugin using https not working for windows

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, https

I am currently using cordova file transfer plugin to download a file and save it locally. I am using https and the server certificate is installed in the device.

It works on IOS and android but it does not work on Windows.

I was able to debug up to plugin's code and it would error in this part with the error message of 'A security problem occurred' and would now return to the application with the FTErr.CONNECTION_ERR:

```
var downloadOperation = download.startAsync();
// update internal TransferOperation object with newly created promise
fileTransferOps[downloadId].promise = downloadOperation;
downloadOperation.then(function () {...}, function(error) 
{
    if (error.message === 'Canceled') {
       resolve(new FTErr(FTErr.ABORT_ERR, source, target, null, null, error));
    } else if (error && error.number === HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_MODIFIED) {
       resolve(new FTErr(FTErr.NOT_MODIFIED_ERR, source, target, 304, null, error));
    } else {
    // in the other way, try to get response property
        var response = download.getResponseInformation();
        if (!response) {
           resolve(new FTErr(FTErr.CONNECTION_ERR, source, target));
        } 
    }
}
```

This is my code in cordova:

```
fileTransfer.download(uri, fileURL, function (entry) {
    console.log('file download successful');
}, function (errorMsg) {
    console.log(errorMsg);
}, false, {
    headers: {"Authorization": authToken},
});`
```

Is there anything I am missing to make this work in windows?

Just to add, download using http was working. 
Https certificate is also valid since ajax get worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN, client certificate is not supported by the BackgroundDownloader.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c25146d2-c051-4367-9745-2b526618dc35/winjsxhr-and-httpclient-work-with-client-certificates-backgrounddownloader-doesnt?forum=winappswithhtml5

So I guess the only way for now would be to create a plugin that uses HttpClient.